# Unable to get current GPS Location co-ordinates

Tags: java, android, google-maps, android-maps, google-maps-mobile

I have been trying hard to get my current location's GPS co-ordinates but my app never locks on to a GPS satellite.

The GPS icon in the notification area just keeps on blinking.

Whereas I tried using Google Maps on Android (the pre-installed app) and that thing is able to lockon in approx 60 secs! In both of the cases my 3G data connection was switched on and working.

**Update**: I am using Android 2.3.3 (HTC Desire S (Factory installed OS; no updates applied)) Logcat output is [here](http://pastebin.com/hvY67Lq9). Now this is without setting `LocationUpdates()`'s min time and min-distance between update to 0, 0.

**Update #2:** My earlier code is [here](http://pastebin.com/Wm6h9VFV)(PasteBin Link).

**Update #3:** Now, I am getting a force close after displaying a Toast .."Available".. in on `onStatusChanged()`.

**Update #4:** Finally..I got it to work.

--

So, is it like that the Google map's app uses some proprietary code for locking on to GPS signals? I have tried using various version of my code. Tried using criteria(s) but never got them to work with GPS. For me getting precise (~50ft accuracy) location co-ordinates through GPS is a must.

My Code:

```
public class LocationDemoActivity extends Activity implements LocationListener {
    LocationManager locationManager;
    StringBuilder builder;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 1000l, 50.0f, this);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPause();
        locationManager.removeUpdates(this);
        locationManager = null;
        Intent i = new Intent(
                android.provider.Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
        startActivity(i);

    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
//      builder = new StringBuilder();
        double lati=location.getLatitude();
        double longi=location.getLongitude();
        double alti=location.getAltitude();
        float acc=location.getAccuracy();
        float speed=location.getSpeed();
        long time=location.getTime();

        System.out.println(lati);
        System.out.println(longi);
        System.out.println(alti);
        System.out.println(acc);
        System.out.println(speed);
        System.out.println(time);

        /*Toast.makeText(this, "Lati: " + lati,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Toast.makeText(this, "Long: " + longi,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Toast.makeText(this, "Alti: " + alti,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Toast.makeText(this, "Acc.: " + acc,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Toast.makeText(this, "Speed: " + speed,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Toast.makeText(this, "Time: " + time,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();*/


        builder.append("Longitide: " + location.getLongitude());
        builder.append('\n');
        builder.append("Latitude: " + location.getLatitude());
        builder.append('\n');
        builder.append("Altitude: " + location.getAltitude());
        builder.append('\n');
        builder.append("Accuracy: " + location.getAccuracy());
        builder.append('\n');
        builder.append("TimeStamp:" + location.getTime());
        builder.append('\n');
        System.out.println(builder.toString());

        Toast.makeText(this, builder.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
        System.out.println("Provider Disabled:");
        Intent intent = new Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
        startActivity(intent);
    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
        System.out.println("Provider Enabled:");
        Toast.makeText(this, "GPS is now enabled...", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
        switch (status) {
        case LocationProvider.OUT_OF_SERVICE:
            System.out.println("Status Changed: Out of Service");
            Toast.makeText(this, "Status Changed: Out of Service",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            break;
        case LocationProvider.TEMPORARILY_UNAVAILABLE:
            System.out.println("Status Changed: Temporarily Unavailable");
            Toast.makeText(this, "Status Changed: Temporarily Unavailable",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            break;
        case LocationProvider.AVAILABLE:
            System.out.println("Status Changed: Available");
            Toast.makeText(this, "Status Changed: Available",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            break;
        }
    }

}
```

Please do answer as it's quite urgent on me and any help is greatly appreciable :)

Thanks..

Comment: In your tets did you have clear open view of the sky? did other applications got the GPS signal?

Comment: @AlexWien Thx for replying fast. Yes, I have a clear view of sky and the pre-installed Google maps (on my HTC Desire S) locks-on just fine(within 60secs on the very same spot). Is there a place where I can get a peek of Google's own code? implementation of Google map's GPS fixer ?

Comment: This has nothing to do with Google maps, you probably set up your code params wrong. Does the onLocationChanged() output anythings to console?

Comment: Have you tried with 0 and 0 as minimum distance and interval, just to see if you get any coordinates at all?

Comment: @AlexWien I don't check it out what `onLocationChanged()` outputs to console LOL am standing out in the open without my laptop :D

Comment: @Gjordis I will try that now :) Thanx for the headsup~

Comment: Hello, It happens to me with some of mobile device especially Old Android devices. Once I start using network, it helps me to get the location though I was not able to fetch using GPS.. I tried so hard, but no luck so far

Comment: @RameshSangili Well, the Google Maps is able to do that on my phone and on the very same spot I am standing at nearly a perfect level..so why not my app? I suspect Google has an enhanced codebase at the time of this android's 2.3.3's release. :| ?

Comment: @Gjordis Nope..even setting the min. distance accuracy and time to 0, 0 isn't helping. Not able to lockon to a GPS satellite.

Comment: Yes, it happens to me as well. Google maps shows the right place, but not from my application. I tried all possible way and left it off..

Comment: @RameshSangili So, you're saying that if you switch on the GPS..and your Google Map's app gets a solid fix of location(using GPS)? The GPS icon appears stable and not blinking? :O On which Android version did you tried that?

Comment: I tried on Android 2.2 and 2.3 India and Singapore devices, but I am in US with Android 2.3 and it works fine for me always

Comment: Beside Standalone GPS services, does your phone also have Google Location Services checked? If so unchecked it and try to see if Google Map app can get a fix. I think Google Map app uses both GPS and Network to get a fix.

Comment: @HoanNguyen ok..here it is.. I tried to fire up the google maps app (at that moment neither..the GPS nor the network was enabled) and it then asked for network to be enabled (#1 possibly wanting to access location using A-GPS)..but I enabled GPS instead :D and then tried to run google maps again..it then started to lockon to my position..I suppose network is definitely not a `required` criteria to get a fix using gmaps IMO..neither of both of them is.. :| (Also, I haven't really checked into Google's `Location services` being enabled on my device..probably they are enabled..)

Comment: I had a brand new LG phone a few months ago. It could not get a GPS fix for an app I was developing. I turned off Google location services and Google Map app could not get a location fix through GPS either. But it would get a fix if I turn on Google location services. My guess is the GPS sensor in your device is broken if in the  location setting of your phone the Google location services is unchecked and Google Map app cannot get a fix with only GPS checked.

Answer (score 1):

It seams pretty obvious that you won't get any Location updates, because you have set the minDistance to 50 meters or 164.042 ft. It appears you have confused this with accuracy.

The `minDistance` parameter is the minimum distance between location updates. So you would have to move at least 50 meters to get a location update.

Also make sure you have a clear view of the sky in order to have GPS signal.

Read more in the documentation

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html

Comment: Fixed* :D yeah..actually it was a typo..Moreover I am banging my head against a wall as I feel there might be an issue with my device's 2.3.3 version. Don't have access to any other device so couldn't really test otherwise.. btw is there really a problem with 2.3.3 based devices in accessing GPS location? or is it just me? :| Are there more users who have faced problem which i am facing on 2.3.3? or HTC Desire S ? :(

Comment: There are no problems in 2.3.3 or any version of Android SDK with the GPS location system. I have used them on more than one ocasion, on different devices without any problems. It seems strange at first, when starting out, that you wont get any new locations if not moving, but you have to understand that this is an hardware sensor, that will not memorize the last known location.

Comment: yep..but all I wanted to know is get a current location's fix and display it through a Toast :| Will try it on a different device or maybe tomorrow on a bright day..maybe sky will become a bit more clear tomm. :D

Answer (score 1):

I asked a related question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14641019/experience-of-location-services-on-android-using-gps-and-network-providers).

To me looks like your GPS on the phone is not able to see the sat's. You need to get our of your office/home onto open air. In my case, I moved to `NetworkProvider` since GPS was just too clumsy.

Also note, that the parameters you give for distance and time are not literal, its the `best guess` that the api makes. So dont count on response times/distances from the API callback.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have all these manifest permissions?

```
ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION

ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION

ACCESS_LOCATION_EXTRA_COMMANDS

ACCESS_MOCK_LOCATION

CONTROL_LOCATION_UPDATES

INTERNET
```

Comment: Yes :) `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />` Have used both of them. And as you can see in the code my `requestLocationUpdates` is already accessing the GPS provider.

Comment: I just added `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CONTROL_LOCATION_UPDATES" /> And got an error saying `Permission is only granted to system apps` ?